# Heroku Sendgrid not sending and not showing errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, sendgrid, railsapps

I am trying to get "Devise Confirmable" email confirmations to work through Sendgrid on Heroku running Rails 4.2

I set up the [rails-devise-pundit](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit/) starter app with Devise Confirmable & Sendgrid options.

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 in development I just needed to set the `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` environment variables and everything works perfectly in development. Signing up sends an email and clicking the link in my inbox redirects me to the app running on my local machine and signs me up as expected.

I deploy the exact same app to Heroku, here I set 3 environment variables using heroku config
`SENDGRID_DOMAIN` (the url of my heroku app)

`SENDGRID_PASSWORD` (private)

`SENDGRID_USERNAME` (private)

I get the same flash saying that the "confirmation link has been sent".

`heroku log` reveals
`Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 461.2ms`

Everything seems to go perfect, except that when the app is running on Heroku the email never arrives, but when running on my dev machine it does.

Switched to Mandrill and reproduced the exact same scenario using Mandrill.

I don't see any error message anywhere and can't see any other issues when scrolling over the logs, how do I go about solving this?

Comment: You could try using a different email service, such as Gmail, and see if it works on Heroku. Given the case you describe, your best bet may be to open a Heroku support ticket.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's great problem solving advice. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found any error messages to help point to this but the problem was with the `DOMAIN_NAME` environment variable that was set on Heroku.

I accidentally included `https://` before the domain name, so my `heroku config` revealed `DOMAIN_NAME: https://example.com`. After removing the `https://` and setting the environment variable to just `example.com` the problem goes away when using Sendgrid or Mandrill and the confirmation emails works as expected.

Comment: This was the cause for me too. And even stranger, devise emails were sending, but others weren't!